# Why doesn't traffic go through router on LAN?

Tags: routing, router, traceroute

So I thought that when two devices are connected to a router, and if they wanted to  communicate with each other, then all the traffic will go through the router(AP). I tried running a traceroute and this is what i got:
[image]

192.168.0.102 is the address of a device on my local network. How is my computer directly connected to this device? Why doesn't the router IP(192.168.0.1) appear as  a hop here?

Comment: if you go to your neighbor house, why would you go to the motorway first and then come back to your street?

Comment: @Zac67 so basically a traceroute only tries to find a path to the entered address, and doesn't actually send data over it, but if I wanted to send data packets to a device on the LAN, it would have to go through the router?

Comment: It is going through it, but as layer-2 (switching) not layer-3 (routing).

Comment: @mayankbudhwani Traceroute probes the IP (L3) path and is completely oblivous to anything below. It does send dummy data, so real data should take the same path. Before you ask, there is no such a thing as a traceroute for Ethernet since L2 lacks TTL and ICMP.

Comment: Traffic will go to router when source and destination are in different subnet . If souce and destination belongs to same subnet then traffic will forward to destination on basis of mac -address table at layer2

Answer (score 1):

Routers forward traffic between networks, or from one network to another. If your devices are on the same network, they can be addressed directly. In that case, there is no need for a router.